# Cannot See Navigation Pane in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

**Core need:**
Using an on-premise installation of Dynamics 365, I want to use a form to create a new `Person` and associate that `Person` with the each `Book` they have read. This is a N:N relationship

**Yak shaving:**
I have created the relevant entities and the N:N relationship but *could not* figure out how to link them. I watched this [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPWQX-rZJv4) video.
This makes it appear that all I need to do is add the relationship to the navigation page in the form editor and it will appear on the form for users. However, the navigation pane is only visible in the form editor and not when trying to use the form.

I cannot find anything on the web that appears to address this issue so I think I've got something seriously backwards. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That video is for 2011 - Older version.

In recent CRM, once you open the record form - on top navigation, you will see small down arrow (caret) icon. Click that to see Associated records navigation.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the caret only appears after the record has been created. Is that a correct?

Comment: @MikePG absolutely, after creation of parent record only - child record can be added.